# Crear un ID personalizado Rails 7

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite3, activerecord

Tengo una pequeña duda, ¿sobre cómo hacer un ID personalizado en `ActiveRecord::Migration`?, de la siguiente manera: mi ID está compuesto por el Año Actual y seguido de 4 digitos, ejemplo: que inicie en **20230001**, se auto incremente, y que en año nuevo, pase a ser **20240001** y vuelva a incrementarse.

Les adjunto una pequeña parte de lo que podría ser mi solución:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :users, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :id, unique: true , auto_increment: true
      t.string :nombre

      t.timestamps
    end
    # execute "ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=20230001"
  end
end
```

En este post de [Custom ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738161/generating-a-custom-id-on-model-create), utilizan `ActiveRecord::Base`, pero yo quiero hacerlo directo en la migración o en el schema para que se genere automáticamente.

Agradezco el tiempo que se toman de leer esto, y cualquier comentario es bienvenido.

Comment: No entiendo, pusiste etiquetas PostgreSQL y SQLite3, pero en el código sale `AUTO_INCREMENT` que es de MySQL. ¿cual es realmente el motor de BD para el cual necesitas una solución? De todas formas, para lo que pides necesitarás crear un procedimiento almacenado que se ejecute sobre la secuencia, sin embargo suena un poco engorrosa tu solución. ¿que pasa cuando llegas al id 20239999? ¿debería pasar a 202310000? ¿por qué no simplemente creas un campo para el año en vez de tratar de reinventar la forma de crear el id?

Comment: Hola, @AlterLagos, Uso ambas bases de datos. Como tal, no tengo una solución, solo la idea de por donde caminar. Por el lado de la secuencia, me interesa más como generar el patrón, de *YYYYDDDDDD*, supongo que debo de investigar más sobre el procedimiento almacenado que me mencionas, y el por qué reinventar el id, quiero tomar el reto :), gracias por tu comentario y saludos cordiales.

Comment: Si usas SQLite, ya es problema, porque no soporta procedimientos almacenados. En general las funcionalidades de SQLite son bastante básicas, así que dudo que se pueda implementar algo como lo pides en dicho motor.

Comment: No debes usar el campo ID para colocar ID's personalizados, porque eso rompe la premisa de convención sobre configuración, y luego tendrás problemas al hacer relaciones entre modelos.  Te sugiero que dejes el ID tal como lo crea Rails y uses un campo diferente para tu ID personalizado.